# Docker: Nginx & PHP Container: no such file or directory

Tags: php, nginx, docker, boot2docker, fig

I want to play around with docker so I created my own 2 container, nginx and php. Both container are build successfully and are published on docker hub. After that I created a fig.yml in my projects folder. If I run `fig up -d` in my terminal, then I got the following error:

```
Recreating playground_php_1...
Cannot start container e087111c...: [8] System error: no such file or directory
```

Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

Here is my fig.yml:

```
web:
  image: mc388/docker-nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  links:
    - php
  volumes:
    - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
  volumes_from:
    - php
php:
  image: mc388/docker-php:latest
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/
```

And here are the links to the config of both docker containers:

- https://github.com/mc388/docker-nginx
- https://github.com/mc388/docker-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying `php:fpm` image has the following line in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile):

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

You then delete this directory, which breaks the default `CMD` command as it uses `WORKDIR` as its base.

I don't know much about PHP and this Docker image, but it's worth reading the documentation and looking at any examples you can find on how to use it; deleting a directory feels like you're working against the image.